# Jquery id not found after .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to show step by step form elements based on the user choices. But if I choose the multiple answer choice, the id of the select element inserted with the .html() function  seems to be not found.

Here is my code on Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/SdF4p/1/

HTML code :

```
     <form id="test">
        <select id="type_of_answer">
            <option selected disabled>Type of answer</option>
            <option value="single">Simple answer</option>
            <option value="multiple">Multiple answer</option>
            <option value="interval">Answer with interval</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <div id="box1">

        </div>
        <div id="box2">

        </div>
    </form>
```

Jquery code :

```
     var nb_answer = '<select id="nb_answer"><option selected disabled>Number of answer</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option></select>';
     var single_answer = '<input id="single_answer" type="text" placeholder="Answer">';
     var multiple_answer1 = '<input id="answer1" type="text" placeholder="Answer 1"><br><input id="answer2" type="text" placeholder="Answer 2"><br><input id="answer3" type="text" placeholder="Answer3">';
     var multiple_answer2 = '<input id="answer1" type="text" placeholder="Answer 1"><br><input id="answer2" type="text" placeholder="Answer 2"><br>';
     var interval = '<input id="interval1" type="text" placeholder="Inf"><br><input id="interval2" type="text" placeholder="Sup">';



 $('#type_of_answer').change(function () {

$('#box2').html(''); //reset

if ($('#type_of_answer').val() == "single") {

    $('#box1').html(single_answer);

} else if ($('#type_of_answer').val() == "multiple") {

    $('#box1').html(nb_answer);

} else {

    $('#box1').html(interval);
}
      });


   $('#nb_answer').change(function () {**//the problem is here. It is clearly not executed**


if ($('#nb_answer').val() == "2") {

    $('#box2').html(multiple_answer1);

} else {

    $('#box2').html(multiple_answer2);
}
  });
```

Comment: your fiddle link is broken

Comment: Sorry, made a small update to show in comment where is the problem : http://jsfiddle.net/SdF4p/1/

Comment: check out @j08691 's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're generating the element dynamically, you need to use .on() instead of .change():

```
$(document).on('change', '#nb_answer', function () {
    $('#box2').html('Bouger');
    if ($('#nb_answer').val() == "2") {
        $('#box2').html(multiple_answer1);
    } else {
        $('#box2').html(multiple_answer2);
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/SdF4p/2/)**

Comment: Your statement is inaccurate, .change(callbackFunction) is a shortcut for .on("change", callbackFunction), you are however correctly using a deferred eventhandler in your code, which makes it work. Please update.

Comment: @Brunis What's false? `.on("change", callbackFunction)` is not the same as `.on('change', '#nb_answer', function () {`. You should probably the event delegation section of the .on() documentation. Oh, and if you can use `.change()` with dynamic elements, please show us an example on jsFiddle.